# Query not running with "*" criteria

Tags: ms-access

I have a query, and I want the criteria to look to a combo box.  I populated the combo box with the following Row Source to add an "All" option:

```
SELECT id, team FROM tblTeams ORDER BY team UNION SELECT "*", "<ALL>" FROM tblTeams;
```

The query runs fine if I choose a team (the criteria is against the id, and the bound column of the combo box is 1).  But if I choose <ALL>, I get a warning:  "This expression is typed incorrectly, or it is too complex to be evaluated.  For example, a numeric expression may contain too many complicated elements.  Try simplifying the expression by assigning parts of the expression to variables."

The field is an integer, so I was thinking the * was causing problems.  I tried changing it to ">0", but that gave me the same error.  Any suggestions for making this work so I don't have to use VBA to manipulate the query (I'm fine to do that, but I feel like it's cleaner if you don't--let me know if that's an errant thought)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that you wish to refer to your form as a criteria line in your query.

Try using Like. This works for me:

```
SELECT Table1.ID, Table1.Team
FROM Table1
WHERE Table1.ID Like [Forms]![Table1]![MyCombo]
```

This does not need any code to work. If a number is selected, that number will be returned, if All is selected, all non-null records will be returned.

Comment: As usual, @Remou, you nailed it!  I'm not sure I understand why it works though--the "Like" makes it return all non-null records?  Or is it "Like *" when it gets evaluated, and that's what makes it return all non-null records?  Thanks!

Comment: Run a query like this `SELECT 1 like "1" As Like1, 1 like "*" As LikeAsterisk, Format( 1 like "1", "true/false") As Like1t, Format(1 like "*", "true/false") As LikeAsteriskt FROM (SELECT Top 1 ID FROM Table1) As t` You will see that 1 is like "1" and like "*"

Answer (score 2):

If your 'id' field from the tblTeams is numeric, trying to use a string such as '*' or '>0' will generate an error when they are joined together by the UNION.

Depending on your needs I would suggest using a query like the one below, where you use a -1 as your 'id', or some other sort of unique numeric 'id'.

Assuming your 'id' fields are all positive numbers.  You can then test for a negative number to determine if all the records should be returned or not.

```
SELECT id, team FROM tblTeams 
UNION 
SELECT -1 as id, "<ALL>" as team FROM tblTeams 
ORDER BY team
```

Alternatively, you can cast your 'id' field into a string, so it's a string just like '*' or '>0'.  The important thing is that the fields be of the same datatype.

```
SELECT Cstr(id), team FROM tblTeams
UNION
SELECT "*" as id, "<All>" as team from tblTeams
ORDER BY team
```

Comment: Thanks, Fink--I like the first answer, but I was really hoping to do it without having to use any code, and I'm not sure how to test for a negative number without doing that.  On the second one, that would change the value of the combo box to a string, but it's the query that drives the datatype of the field--or would you then add a cstr to the query field as well?  I'll actually go test that, though Remou had a solution that modified just the query to allow for the correct result.

Comment: I tested the Cstr (on both the query field and the id of the combo box), and the report ran when I selected <All> but didn't return any records.